# Is "si mem" acceptable?

Tags: word-usage

I've seen people use *si mem* to mean *oneself*, particularly in the phrase *per si mem* to mean *by oneself*. However, it seems to me that just *si* is plenty.

Is this grammatically correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Per si mem* is a grammatically correct phrase, though it does not have the same exact meaning as *per si*. Essentially, *per si* means that something is using itself/its existence to do something, while *per si mem* means that it is doing something without outside help. *Per si mem* has a connotation of action with intent, while *per si* implies that whatever happened just happened by virtue of the thing existing.

- *La reĝino per si inspiris nin.* -> "The queen inspired us [by existing]."
- *La reĝino per si mem inspiris nin.* -> "The queen inspired us on her own/single handedly."

Search " per si " on [Tekstaro.com](http://tekstaro.com/) for more examples.

Answer (score 4):

*Si*, *si mem*, and *per si mem* are all correct, depending on what you want to express.

There are well over 100 hits from Zamenhof at Tekstaro for *si mem* and 29 for *per si mem*.